# How do I refer to the family of MinGW forks?

Tags: mingw, terminology

I recently learned that "MinGW" is trademarked ([[1]](http://www.spi-inc.org/corporate/trademarks/) [[2]](http://www.spi-inc.org/projects/mingw/)) and refers only to the version distributed from http://mingw.org

There are a number of forks and alternate distributions of the original MinGW (for example [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php), the [nuwen distribution](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) and [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/)).

I previously referred to all these as the "MinGW platform" (and noted any quirks and differences). Is there an existing term that refers to all these?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to them as exactly what they are: works *derived* from original MinGW code. All such forks are authorized, under the terms of the MinGW.org licences, but they *must not* be described *as* MinGW; that use of the trademark has not been authorized by MinGW.org, (for whom [SPI](http://www.spi-inc.org/corporate/trademarks/) acts as agent in matters relating to registration and use of the trademark), and thus would constitute infringement, (an infringement of which the [nuwen distribution](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) is blatantly guilty, because it is described as MinGW, with no authorization to make any such use of the trademark).

As far as tagging on SO is concerned, the `mingw` tag should be *strictly* reserved for use in relation to the MinGW.org products; any other use could be construed as trademark infringement. When referring to the mingw-w64 fork, you may use the `mingw-w64` tag.  There may be other tags to suit the other forks you mention; if not, perhaps they should be created.